# select image except for ROIs in imagej

Tags: imagej

I have a question regarding image processing in imagej. Is there a way how to select a background except for multiple ROIs that I have created in the picture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using ImageJ macros, any other scripting language, or developing in Java? If it's just about GUI usage, have a look at the [ROI manager documentation](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:ROI-Manager...) and consider asking on the ImageJ forum: http://forum.imagej.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you made several ROIs and you want to select everything in the image that is outside them.

If so, you can do it as follows. Most of this is using the [ROI Manager](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:ROI-Manager...) as recommended by Jan.

1. Make your ROIs, adding each one to the ROI Manager by pressing T.
2. In the ROI Manager, select all the ROIs, then click More >> and choose OR. This combines all the ROIs into one.
3. Add this combined ROI to the ROI Manager (press T) and select it in the Manager.
4. In the main ImageJ menu, go to Edit > Selection > Make Inverse. Now you have a ROI that is everything except your original ROIs.

--Theresa

Comment: You're welcome! The forum at forum.imagej.net, or the mailing list at imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html are great for ImageJ usage questions too.